# Access web page content using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to access and manipulate the data of the web page.
For primary testing purpose I used the w3schools websit but I am unable to access the content using following code:

```
import urllib as url
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

web_data = url.urlopen("www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml")
str_data = web_data.read()
print str_data
```

These are the errors I am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\webpage.htlm.py", line 4, in <module>
    web_data = url.urlopen("www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 469, in open_file
    return self.open_local_file(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 483, in open_local_file
    raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the path specified: 'www.w3schools.com\\xml\\cd_catalog.xml'
```

Comment: `open_file`/`open_local_file` means it's looking for that file **on your computer**, not on the internet...

Comment: Try adding http:// before your URL.

Comment: URLs start with a protocol. Add `http://`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A URL begins with a protocol.

Here, you probably wanted `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml`.